# Regex needed in Java to handle dynamic string value

Tags: java, regex

I have a string with the following value:

> TOTAL DUE-STATEMENT$240.05911 Fee$10.00FRANCHISE TAX$.172VSALES TAX$.53LOCAL-TAX$.23SERVICE DISCOUNT-$50.00PAYMENT - THANK YOU-$100.00HBO+STARLET$100.00

I need to split this string as a key/value pair.

```
TOTAL DUE-STATEMENT $240.05
911 Fee $10.00
FRANCHISE TAX $.17
2VSALES TAX $.53
LOCAL-TAX $.23
SERVICE DISCOUNT -$50.00
PAYMENT - THANK YOU -$100.00
HBO+STARLET $100.00
```

My String value will be always dynamic and the description is dynamic except `911 Fee`
I wrote a regex as follows.

```
([911 a-zA-Z |911 a-zA-Z|a-zA-Z |a-zA-Z \\-? a-zA-Z|! ?|+? ]+)(-?\\$[0-9|,]*\\.[0-9][0-9])
```

I am getting the key/value pairs correctly, except the description contains numerals and letters and special characters. My output is as follows:

```
TOTAL DUE-STATEMENT $240.05
911 Fee $10.00
FRANCHISE TAX $.17
SALES TAX $.53   ** Which is wrong**(Expected is 2VSALES TAX as key)
LOCAL-TAX $.23
SERVICE DISCOUNT -$50.00
PAYMENT - THANK YOU-  $100.00 "-" is coming as key (Expected is PAYMENT - THANK YOU)
STARLET $100.00 **- Which is wrong** (Expected is HBO+STARLET)
```

Could some one please help me what I need to change in this regex?

Comment: This is a brilliant question. It has a clear objective, sample text which covers all the edge cases the requester could find, desired output, and my +1 vote.

Answer (score 2):

Example: http://regexr.com?35dsq

Use this RegEx

```
/([-]{0,1}\$\d*\.\d\d)/g
```

It finds a `$` followed by any number of digits, then a `.` then 2 digits.

Then in your replace use

```
 \1\n
```

Comment: You'll miss the negative sign that appears sometimes before $.

Comment: @dda Thanks for that.  Should be fixed now.

Comment: Why the down-vote?  In the example, input matches expected output exactly.

Answer (score 1):

## Description

This regular expression solution assumes the money column sometimes has a `-` prefix but always contains a `$` followed by zero or more digits, a dot, and exactly 2 digits. The rest of the characters are part of a name.

`([^$]*?)(-?\$\d*\.\d{2})`

[image]

Each capture group 1 will have the name, and capture group 2 will have the dollar value.

## Examples:

Working example: http://www.rubular.com/r/9ODCQXyFoZ

**Sample Text**

```
TOTAL DUE-STATEMENT$240.05911 Fee$10.00FRANCHISE TAX$.172VSALES TAX$.53LOCAL-TAX$.23SERVICE DISCOUNT-$50.00PAYMENT - THANK YOU-$100.00HBO+STARLET$100.00
```

**Java Code**

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
class Module1{
  public static void main(String[] asd){
  String sourcestring = "source string to match with pattern";
  Pattern re = Pattern.compile("([^$]*?)(-?\\$\\d*\\.\\d{2})",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
  Matcher m = re.matcher(sourcestring);
  int mIdx = 0;
    while (m.find()){
      for( int groupIdx = 0; groupIdx < m.groupCount()+1; groupIdx++ ){
        System.out.println( "[" + mIdx + "][" + groupIdx + "] = " + m.group(groupIdx));
      }
      mIdx++;
    }
  }
}
```

**Capture Groups**

```
$matches Array:
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => TOTAL DUE-STATEMENT$240.05
            [1] => 911 Fee$10.00
            [2] => FRANCHISE TAX$.17
            [3] => 2VSALES TAX$.53
            [4] => LOCAL-TAX$.23
            [5] => SERVICE DISCOUNT-$50.00
            [6] => PAYMENT - THANK YOU-$100.00
            [7] => HBO+STARLET$100.00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => TOTAL DUE-STATEMENT
            [1] => 911 Fee
            [2] => FRANCHISE TAX
            [3] => 2VSALES TAX
            [4] => LOCAL-TAX
            [5] => SERVICE DISCOUNT
            [6] => PAYMENT - THANK YOU
            [7] => HBO+STARLET
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => $240.05
            [1] => $10.00
            [2] => $.17
            [3] => $.53
            [4] => $.23
            [5] => -$50.00
            [6] => -$100.00
            [7] => $100.00
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering there are always two decimal places

Your regex could be simplified to

```
.+?[$]\d*[.]\d{2}
```

You need to **match** the pattern with above regex not split

```
Matcher m =Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input);
while(m.find())
{
m.group();
}
```

Comment: You'll miss the negative sign that appears sometimes before $.

Comment: @dda this RegEx will match the lines the OP is wanting to separate by.  The only issue is that OP has desired output containing spaces before the `$` which this will not easily allow.

Comment: @DavidStarkey have you tried..am using `.+?` and since regex engine goes from left to right it would match perfectly..first try then comment

Comment: @Anirudh [I have tried](http://regexr.com?35dt9).  I mentioned that your RegEx WORKS, the only issue is that the OP has spaces after the dollar amounts (`TOTAL DUE-STATEMENT$240.05` becomes `TOTAL DUE-STATEMENT $240.05`) which your RegEx will not easily accomplish

Answer (score 0):

As your price format is known, search for it, and everything in between is the description:

```
    String in = "TOTAL DUE-STATEMENT$240.05911 Fee$10.00FRANCHISE TAX$.172VSALES TAX$.53LOCAL-TAX$.23SERVICE DISCOUNT-$50.00PAYMENT - THANK YOU-$100.00HBO+STARLET$100.00";
    Pattern price = Pattern.compile("-?\\$\\d*\\.\\d{2}");
    Matcher matcher = price.matcher(in);
    int offset = 0;
    while (matcher.find(offset)) {
        String description = in.substring(offset, matcher.start());
        String value = matcher.group();
        System.out.println(description + " " + value);
        offset = matcher.end();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String test = "TOTAL DUE-STATEMENT$240.05911 Fee$10.00FRANCHISE TAX$.172VSALES TAX$.53LOCAL-TAX$.23SERVICE DISCOUNT-$50.00PAYMENT - THANK YOU-$100.00HBO+STARLET$100.00";
        java.util.regex.Pattern p = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("(?<KEY>.+?(?=-?\\$[\\d,]*\\.\\d{2}))(?<VAL>-?\\$[\\d,]*\\.\\d{2})");
        java.util.regex.Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
        while(m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group("KEY") + " : " + m.group("VAL"));
        }
    }
}
```

You just need a non-greedy match for the KEY .+? and then a lookahead for the VALUE that will always end in a point and 2 digits for the cents.

Answer (score -1):

This should do it:

```
^(.+) (-?\$\d*\.\d\d)$
```

The second half of the regex matches the dollar amount, including the optional - sign. The first part takes everything else except the separating space.

Comment: Works for me with the text provided by the OP -- separate lines.